# SAPUI5 - ComboBox/Dropdown or Menu to display Hierarchy data

Tags: sapui5

I need to make a ComboBox or Dropdown, which can have nested data, such as this

```js
  var data = [{
    "text": "A",
    "icon": "1.gif",
    "innerObject": [{
        "text": "A.A",
        "icon": "1-1.gif"
    }, {
        "text": "A.B",
        "icon": "1-2.gif"
    }]
}, {
    "text": "B",
    "icon": "2.gif",
    "innerObject": [{
        "text": "B.A",
        "icon": "2-1.gif"
    }]
}]
```

I need to display it in a ComboBox or Dropdown, which can display its hierarchy. Is there any sample in SAPUI5 for this?

I also tried exploring Menu for this requirement, but I am not able to load menu and submenu dynamically.
-Prateek

Answer (score 1):

Selects (Dropdown) and  Comboboxes supports only Item objects, which cannot contain other Items.

You can use Value Help Dialog to display any kind of data in a popup (for example a tree table, which supports hierarchical structures).

Of course, you can create your own control, but it's the most complicated solution.

Comment: Hello, can you help me creating own control. Can you give me some direction on how to do it.

Comment: Yes, here is the official documentation in this topic: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db.html

Comment: Thanks @nistv4n I was trying to ask, what strategy to take to build such component

Comment: As starting point, you can investigate the [TreeTable](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.TreeTable.JSONTreeBinding/preview). However, I do not recommend to create a control like this, because it can lead to compatibility issues. What about creating a select, and if user selects an item with sub-items, a new select is displayed and the child elements can be selected from that? Nevertheless, the recommended UI5 way is a Value Help Dialog, it's responsive and supported officially.